# BubbleTextView in Launcher2

Tags: android, view, android-launcher

I'm a new Android programmer. I'm exploring Laucher2 application in Android source code package. There is a strange View extending from TextView - "BubbleTextView" that is used in application.xml and folder_icon.xml. Is there anybody know what this view really means? What is its purpose? (I've gone through file BubbleTextView.java but I am still confused about it)
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

icon is laid on with the help of BubbleTextView in launcher2. setCompundDrawableWithIntrinsicBounds() is used to place the icon above the BubbleTextView . TextView is implemented here to create some kind of effects i guess